# É possível alterar uma String de um método em tempo de execução?

Tags: java, string, reflexão

Se eu tiver tiver uma `String` fixa dentro de um método é possível ela ser alterada usando reflexão ou algo do gênero? 
Exemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String nome = getName();
    boolean valid = isValidName(nome);
    if (valid) {
        System.out.print("Seu nome é valido!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Seu nome é inválido!");
    }
}
```

Eu precisaria alterar a mensagem "Seu nome é inválido!" para "Nome invalido." isso em tempo de execução, ou seja, após compilar e executar o programa eu precisaria editar essa mensagem.

Estou trabalhando com uma API que esta em inglês, o cliente pediu para min traduzi-la 100%. A API possui mensagens configuráveis, onde você pode simplesmente ir no arquivo lang.txt e trocar as mensagens, porém existem algumas mensagens que não estão disponíveis nesse arquivo lang.txt então eu tive que edita-las usando reflexão, porém me deparei com algumas mensagens que estão "fixas" (não sei se esse é o termo correto) e eu precisaria editar essas mensagens... essas mensagens seguem o exemplo acima.

Comment: Alterar como? Não tá muito claro o que pretende fazer

Comment: Quero trocar a mensagem "Seu nome é inválido!" para "Nome não valido" por exemplo.

Comment: Quando? Clique em [edit] e explique o que voce está fazendo, o que está tentando desenvolver e não está conseguindo. Sua duvida está superficial demais. Explicando nesses detalhes que te falei, fica mais facil entender.

Comment: @Articuno fiz uma edição do post agora explicando melhor o caso, espero que entenda... eu sinceramente acho que isso que estou tentando fazer é impossível... já trabalhei algumas vezes com reflection mas acho que nem tudo nessa vida é possível ><

Comment: as chamadas de mensagem são sempre com `System.out`? Ou foi um exemplo demonstrativo

Comment: Foi um exemplo demonstrativo... Acabei de estudar e fazer MUITOS testes com refleciton e methods, e acho que isso que estou tentando fazer é impossível :(

Comment: Acho que a unica "maneira" de se fazer isso é tentar interpretar o método que envia a mensagem para o usuário, como a API é uma API de um jogo, acho que não deve ser muito difícil interpretar os pacotes que são enviados no chat do jogador.

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa necessariamente usar reflection para isso, você pode *criar sua própria API*.

Já precisei fazer isso, com vários jars antigos e sem suporte cujo código fonte ninguém possuía, geralmente internos, mas também já aconteceu de precisar alterar um jar de terceiros, que nem o site existia mais.

Usa o programa jd-gui (ou qualquer descompilador que lhe agrade) para ver todo o código fonte do seu jar.

Cria um novo projeto na sua IDE e copia os códigos do descompilador para lá, faz as suas modificações e exporta para um novo arquivo.

Acredito que dessa forma é até mais fácil, pode até alterar de forma a fazer todas as strings serem carregadas de um properties.

Comment: Infelizmente o JAR que eu tenho pesa 18MB e ele não é opensource, trabalhar com engenharia reversa neste casso seria praticamente impossível... ia ser messes de trabalho gastos para editar 4 ou 5 frases.

Comment: Não recomendo usar jd-gui... ele é de longe um dos piores decompiladores... recomendo luytem ou ainda se preferir use um online http://www.javadecompilers.com/ (recomendo)